# Using templates to track an object using opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, template-matching

I am currently working on a project where I would have to detect new objects appearing on the camera feed over the background.I am cropping the images of the detected objects and storing them in a vector of matrices.When I have sufficient amount of images,I destroy the background and try to track the previous detected object.Since,I destroyed the background,the only information I have about the object to be tracked is those cropped images.So,I used `matchTemplate()` to find matches for the images.But,I couldn't get any matches.I am including a pic of one of the images I am using as Template

[image]

This roi was cropped from
[image].

Earlier, I used template matching to track my face and it worked fine[image: template used to track my face]
[image: detected face]

But only difference is, I provided the cropped images during face detection and in  my current algorithm roi to be used as template automatically gets cropped  from main image.

I provided images I used for both my projects.I think there maybe some problem with my automated cropped templates.I would like ,if someone points me in the right direction.
I am using opencv libraries with c++.

**EDIT:**[image: testing image]

For my initial testing,I was remaining in the same position as of my templates stored to get maximum detection.But,there is no match.I am providing an image in which templates should be matched.

Comment: is your cropped template not recognized in the full image? Obviously, if your move your arm (for example), your template doesn't work anymore. Can you provide target images where you want to detect your template?

Comment: darn that dream. using template matching for anything from a webcam won't work, due to perspective / rotation / scaling issues. also, you can only apply it to *rigid* structures.

Comment: @berak,As I mentioned above I am remaining in the same position for my initial testing.So, there should be no problems of perspective / rotation / scaling involved.